# A Proof of Zorn's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

I have a question about a step in following proof:
[A Simple Proof of Zorn's Lemma.pdf](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs)

Here the excerpt:

[image]

My question is why in $v \in P(B,y)$, Indeed we have $v < u <y$ by construction but why $v \in B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u \in P(B,y)$ then $u \in P(A,x)$, so if we have $v \in A$ and $v < u$ we have $v \in P(A,x)$. And we have $P(A,x) \subseteq B$, as he notes a couple of lines earlier, so $v \in B$ follows.